# Where clause available in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a scenario while developing an application. I have an object named MyImage as:

```
function MyImage(imgUrl,id){
   this.ImageUrl = ko.observable(imgUrl);
   this.Id = ko.observable(id);
   this.Attributes = ko.observableArray([]);

   var theWidth = new TheAttributes(0,'width','120px');
   this.Attributes().push(theWidth);

   var theHeight = new TheAttributes(0,'height','120px');
   this.Attributes().push(theHeight );
}
```

A lot of css attributes can get added in Attributes array by the end user,
the attributes are defined as:

```
function TheAttributes(id,attName,attValue)
{
   this.Id = ko.observable(id);
   this.AttName = ko.observable(attName);
   this.AttValue = ko.observable(attValue);
}
```

End user will have a list of images, s/he can select one by clicking on it and once an image is selected, user shall be able to edit its info and attributes. At the moment what I am thinking to do is like:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.SelectedImage">
    Image File selection controls and than
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Attributes">
        <!-- ko if: AttName == 'width' -->
        <li>Show label and text field for width</li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: AttName == 'height' -->
        <li>Show label and text field for height</li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: AttName == 'backgroundColor' -->
        <li>Show label and Dropdown field for color selection</li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wanted to ask if this is the correct approach or is there any better alternative and is there any "where" clause kind of mechanism available in knockout so that I can maintain the sequence of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put that logic inside your template. Instead, I would create a list of available attributes in your view model:

```
function MyImage(imgUrl,id){
   this.AvailableAttributes = {
       width: 'Show label and text field for width',
       height: 'Show label and text field for height',
       backgroundColor: 'Show label and Dropdown field for color selection'
   };
   this.ImageUrl = ko.observable(imgUrl);
   this.Id = ko.observable(id);
   this.Attributes = ko.observableArray([]);

   var theWidth = new TheAttributes(0,'width','120px');
   this.Attributes().push(theWidth);

   var theHeight = new TheAttributes(0,'height','120px');
   this.Attributes().push(theHeight );
}
```

So you can do the following in your template:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.SelectedImage">
    Image File selection controls and than
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Attributes">
        <!-- ko if: AvailableAttributes[AttName] -->
            <li data-bind="text: AvailableAttributes[AttName]"></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

To maintain the sequence you could write a computed which sorts `Attributes` based on the order of `AvailableAttributes`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, in AvailableAttributes shall I keep the html of each attribute? The text 'Show label and text field for width' basically means that I will be showing a label and a text field for width attribute.

Comment: Where possible, you want to prevent HTML code inside your viewmodels. `AvailableAttributes ` now only contains the labels of the attributes. You can extend it with other metadata by changing the items like this: `width: { label: 'Show label and text field for width', inputType: 'text'}`.

Comment: Makes sense to me, I will give it a shot and will update you as soon as possible.